# newly generated personal access token in GitHub is not visible

Tags: security, github, token, personal-access-token

I am trying to generate a personal access token, I have followed steps mentioned in github documentation for the same

Expected output:

[image]

but instead, the **token is not visible** as soon as click the generate button

Actual output:

[image]

[proof-of-concept video](https://youtu.be/bs3W7QkeZ3w)

why the token is not visible here, are there any changes needed to be done before generating personal access token?

Comment: same issue here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cleared browser data (cache, cookies, old form fields data) and disabled all addons/extensions, which made PAT to be visible

**Note**: whenever a UI functionality not working, `it must be checked with different platforms/browsers`, as there might be compatibility issue. Also, `clean cache, cookies, old form fields data of the browser`, such data might cause functionality to produce unexpected results or not at all

Answer (score -1):

I can not reproduce your problem.
After "generate" the token is shown.

But you can click in the list on your token and regenerate it and see a new token.
[image]

Comment: it's not even visible for regenerate token as well